# How to apply cumcount to two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with NAME and DATE. I want to create a count column that will only increment if the date is different. Please see the third column below:

```
Name    Date          COLUMN I NEED
----    ----          -------------
Bob     11-01-2019          1
Bob     11-01-2019          1
Bob     11-20-2019          2
Mike    12-01-2019          1
Mike    12-02-2019          2
Mike    12-03-2019          3
Steve   01-01-2019          1
Steve   01-01-2019          1
```

I tried using:

```
df['COLUMN RESULT'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Date'].cumsum() + 1

Name    Date          COLUMN RESULT
----    ----          -------------
Bob     11-01-2019          1
Bob     11-01-2019          2
Bob     11-20-2019          3
Mike    12-01-2019          1
Mike    12-02-2019          2
Mike    12-03-2019          3
Steve   01-01-2019          1
Steve   01-01-2019          2
```

But it will increment no matter what date it is. Thanks for the help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
df['result'] = df.Date.ne(df.Date.shift()).groupby(df.Name).cumsum().astype(int)
```

---

```
    Name        Date  result
0    Bob  11-01-2019       1
1    Bob  11-01-2019       1
2    Bob  11-20-2019       2
3   Mike  12-01-2019       1
4   Mike  12-02-2019       2
5   Mike  12-03-2019       3
6  Steve  01-01-2019       1
7  Steve  01-01-2019       1
```

Comment: If the first `Mike` is `11-20-2019` instead of `12-01-2019`, this solution will return `0` instead of `1`. I may be wrong, but I got impression that the desired output implies every new `Name` group would start from `1`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

using `groupby` `apply` and `shift`

```
df['result'] = df.groupby('Name')['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())
print(df)
     Name     Date  given_output result
0    Bob 2019-11-01      1       1
1    Bob 2019-11-01      1       1
2    Bob 2019-11-20      2       2
3   Mike 2019-12-01      1       1
4   Mike 2019-12-02      2       2
5   Mike 2019-12-03      3       3
6  Steve 2019-01-01      1       1
7  Steve 2019-01-01      1       1
```